# Do LEGO sets go on sale on black friday?

Tags: shopping

I'm considering buying a LEGO set (42110) and with black friday coming up I was wondering whether they go on sale for black friday on amazon or the official LEGO store/shop at home. I looked at the price guide for various LEGO Technic sets on The Camelizer, a Chrome addon that only works with Amazon and I saw no significant drop in prices around black friday. In fact the prices went up by quite a bit, most likely due to demand for the holidays. I don't particularly remember there being a black friday sale at the LEGO store or the shop at home website, but hopefully someone can remember if there is a black friday sale. Any information would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Retailers adjust their pricing strategy from year to year, so what happened in previous years may not be necessarily an indication of what will happen this year.

In general, LEGO offers Double VIP Points and some sets on sale (usually stuff they want to get rid off, not sets that are popular recent releases) and throws in some freebies. Amazon does their own thing, mostly competing with Wal-Mart and not LEGO directly.

I have also noticed that in the past 2-3 years, Black Friday sales are not the best either from LEGO directly or retailers. However, the couple of weeks leading up to Black Friday can be pretty good. Again, this is not an indication of what will happen this year, it is just what I noticed in the past few years.

LEGO Technic sets, especially the large ones from the current year, rarely go on sale. So, if you can get something like Double VIP Points (basically giving you 10% off), is not bad. On Amazon, I have seen as much as 30% off before Black Friday on some of the larger LEGO Technic sets and that was considered exceptional.

Some people missed out because they thought prices will be even better during Black Friday. That did not happen. And that brings up another point. Don't be greedy with looking for the ultimate sale and risk missing out altogether. Look at the price you would be happy with, willing to pay, and is reasonable. Then, just go for it.

Comment: Amazon (at least in Europe) sometimes offer much better deals during the year than on Black Friday. Especially for Technic sets.

Comment: @Alex, yes, that's my experience as well. The best ones I have seen were a few weeks leading up to Black Friday. I'm in the US.